# Enabling Email Notifications in Github for all the collaborators

Tags: git, github, git-bash

We all are new to github. I can enable this email notification only for two email accounts for the github repo which is owned to me. I need to enable this feature for all of my collaborators. But they haven't that AddService option as they said. So please can anyone provides a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Tell them to click on [image: Watch button] on the repo page.